# save webcam image as file and load it as background image on canvas, background image does not change

Tags: caching, canvas, background-image, webcam

I am trying to save image as file from webcam and then load it as background image(whenever i press snap button). However, when i press snap button, my file change but background image (on canvas) stays the same. So background image is always first snap image. When i clear cache my background image on canvas set to latest file. Whats the problem?

index.html

```
<button id ="snap">Snap Photo</button><br>
<canvas id ="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<video id = "video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

file.js

```
window.onload = function() {

  backgroundImage = null;

  // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  // Get access to the camera!
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    }).then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    });
  }

  //get canvas and context element
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  // Trigger photo take
  document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      var canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',false);
      ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
      ajax.send(canvasData);
      backgroundImage = new Image();
      backgroundImage.src = "test.png";
  });

  //call update function every 80 nanoseconds
  setInterval(function() {
    update(c, ctx);
  }, 80);
}


function update(c, ctx) {
    //draw backgroundImage
  if (backgroundImage) {
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, 640, 480);
  }
 }
```

testSave.php

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
  // Get the data
  $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

  // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
  // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

  // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  //echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

  // Save file. This example uses a hard coded filename for testing,
  // but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
  $fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (backgroundImage) {
      backgroundImage = new Image();
      backgroundImage.src = "test.png";` You are setting its src to `'test.png'` every time just before drawing it. What do you expect to happen ? Also, why don't you display the canvas directly ?

Comment: It was just for testing purpose. I edited it. Thanks. What do you mean display the canvas directly?